# How in Appium Python run tests on two connected android devices, and verify that actions on one have expected results on the other or both?

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, appium-android

I have two android devices. Server app running on one of them and viewer app running on the other. I want to write tests in Python for Appium which verify that inputting events on one of them yields results on both. How do I do that?

I have Appium server running and I can automate actions on single device with python via Appium Python Client.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.